# Uneven edge on 90deg linear gradient

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to use this CSS to create a background that is half one colour and half transparent.

```
linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(238, 238, 241, 0.9) 50%, transparent 0);
```

This works fine most of the time, but at certain browser widths, the split between the colour/transparent sections becomes uneven and jagged.

I've looked at the common rendering bugs when, for example, using a 45deg angle. But never come accross it for a straight line.

My assumption is the issue is caused by subpixel rendering issues as the width is a percentage. Anyone any ideas on how I might combat this?

[image: Jagged line on linear gradient]

Comment: replace the 90deg by `to right` and make the transparent at 50.5%

Comment: Hello Temani. I gave that a shot and it worked! Not sure how that fixes it but it does and I've gone through different screen sizes and it's holding up! I managed to keep what I had and just change the width to 50.1% and it still worked so going to keep it at that so it's closer to 50%. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments, Temani suggested I try using a decimal percentage.

I've changed my CSS to

```
linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(238, 238, 241, 0.9) 50.1%, transparent 0);
```

And it's now working. Still not really sure why it was happening but at least it's working visually! Would love to know more if anyone can expand on this.

Comment: `And it's not working.` you meant it's now* working? :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue mainly arises in chrome only few days back I face same issue then I fixed it using css property i.e

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-background-clip: content-box;
padding: 1px;
```

May be it helps you !!

Comment: Hi Abhijeet. I tried this and it didn't work, unfortunately. Thank you though!

Comment: You can try outline:1px solid transparent;